# Input not binding correctly with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, mvvm, vue.js

I'm still relatively new to `Vue.js` and am having an issue binding one of my inputs to my viewmodel.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var viewModel = new Vue({
    el: "#InventoryContainer",
    data: {
        upcCode: "",
        component: {
            Name: ""
        }
    },
    methods: {
        upcEntered: function (e) {
            if (this.upcCode.length > 0){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Component/GetByUpc",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {
                        upc: this.upcCode
                    }
                }).done(function (response) {
                    if (response.exists) {
                        $("#ComponentInformation").toggleClass("hidden");
                        this.component = response.component;
                    } else {
                        alert("No component found.");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="form-horizontal row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4">UPC Code</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input id="ComponentUPC" class="form-control" placeholder="Scan or enter UPC Code" v-on:blur="upcEntered" v-model="upcCode" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="ComponentInformation" class="hidden">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly v-model="component.Name" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the issue is that even when I enter a valid UPC code and I assign the component to my ViewModel, the input that is bound to `component.Name` does not update with the component name. And when I enter into the console `viewModel.component.Name` I can see that it returns `""`.

But if I put an alert in my `ajax.done` function after I've assigned the component and it looks like this `alert(this.component.Name)` it alerts the name of the component.

Any ideas of where I'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use that line 
`this.component = response.component;` 
because of the `this`-variable.

You should put the line 
`var self = this`
before your ajax call and use `self.component` instead of `this.component`

Comment: Yep, that is exactly what the problem was. I should have caught that but didn't. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

in order for vue to work you need to define the parent container with id InventoryContainer

```
<div id="InventoryContainer" class="form-horizontal row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
 ....
```

here is the updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/hdqdmscv/
here is the updated fiddle based on your comment

https://jsfiddle.net/hdqdmscv/2/

(replace this with name of vue variable in ajax)

Comment: That seems to be done, other wise this would not work "But if I put an alert in my ajax.done function after I've assigned the component and it looks like this alert(this.component.Name) it alerts the name of the component."

Comment: @Reiner i have updated my fiddle, let me if it works.